# What's the difference between you, you had, you have?

Tags: grammar

Are these all interchangeable or do they have different meanings?

Someone you loved.

Someone you had loved.

Someone you have loved.

Comment: They are not interchangeable.  Have a look at [Ell.SE]: I'm sure this has been covered there already.

Comment: Try parsing it the other way to get *loved, had loved, have loved* instead.

Answer (score 0):

The brief answer:

- Someone you loved - In the past. You probably don't love someone anymore.
- Someone you had loved - In the past before something happened. You no longer love someone.
- Someone you have loved - From a time in the past up until the present. You still love someone.